# mkdirs() is getting executed successfully but the folder is not visible in Honor 9i

Tags: java, android, mkdir, mkdirs

I am trying to create a folder and subfolder namely "CJI/Export" in "Internal Memory" using the following code. To ensure that the command is successfully executed, I have added Toast Messages in all states.

I tried running the code on two devices: "Redmi Note 3" & "Honor 9i".

In Redmi Note-3, I am getting the results as expected. The command is creating the folder & subfolder successfully.

But in Honor 9i, I also shows the toast message "Export Folder created successfully", but I can't see any such folder or sub-folder in the device manager (internal memory). Also, on closing the app and launching it again, I get the same toast message "Export Folder created successfully".

package com.example.app.activities;

```
public class HomeScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements{
    private String dirPathExport;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        dirPathExport= createMediaDirExport(HomeScreenActivity.this);
    }


    public static String createMediaDirExport(Context context) {
        String dirPath="";
        try {
            dirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/CJI/Export";
            File dir_temp = new File(dirPath);
            if (!dir_temp.exists()) {
                dir_temp.mkdirs();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Export Folder created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, "Export Folder already present", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error during folder creation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return dirPath;
    }
}
```

Expected Result is to get the folder in Internal Memory in Honor 9i

Answer (score 0):

go to `App Info`-> `Permissions` of your application and **enable** `Storage` permission.